# Removing repeated characters from a list in python

Tags: python

So, im trying to remove repeated characters from the following 2 lists I have, My code works for the Int's but not for my String's?!

Any tips?
Code is as follows:

```
list = [0,1,0,1,2,2,3,4,5,7,9,8,10,1,1,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]

list2 = ['z','r','a','z','x','b','z','a','f','f','f','x','t','t','o','p','a','b','v','e','q','p','c','x']

for i in list:

    list.sort()
    compteur = 0

    while compteur < len(list):

        if i == list[compteur]:

            list.remove(list[compteur])
            compteur+=1
        elif i != list[compteur]:
            compteur+=1
```

Under for i in list: everything should be indented idk why i was not able to make it appear the correct way.

Comment: I am going through the basics, just went through using a set, and yes it makes things easier. But we are not allowed to use them yet... Thanks!

Comment: Well it does work for the strings(`list2`) too. [Have a look](http://repl.it/2Tt).

Comment: @user4179570 what are you allowed to use then? It helps when asking what constraints your instructor/teacher/whatever has stated as well as your experience, so that members don't waste time answering with something that's not suitable for your requirements.

Comment: One thing you should consider when you are not sure what your code is doing: use print statements: every time you modify a list or remove an element, print a helpful message and print the new value of the thing you have modified. You will be able to watch each step of its transformation that way.

Comment: I appreciate your feedback, I will mention any restrictions in my next post. Please be reassured that I do appreciate your comments/answer(s) and  I went to look into sets right after you posted!

Comment: Leaving this here for the future: The [`unique_everseen` and `unique_justseen` recipes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes) are a good place to start when solving a problem like this (though not applicable to this case, since using `unique_justseen` would require sorting the input, and `unique_everseen` uses a `set`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you said that you are not allowed to make usage of sets, you can make it verifying each element and inserting it on a third unique elements list as:

```
int_list = [0,1,0,1,2,2,3,4,5,7,9,8,10,1,1,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]

char_list = ['z','r','a','z','x','b','z','a','f','f','f','x','t','t','o','p','a','b','v','e','q','p','c','x']
```

Example with **int_list**:

```
unique_list = []
for el in int_list:
    if el not in unique_list:
        unique_list.append(el)
    else:
        print "Element already in the list"
```

The result would be:

```
>>> print unique_list
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

Comment: TY for your post, I appreciate your help! i believe unique_list.append[el] should be unique_list.append(el)

Comment: I didnt even think of using the if el not in 'new list', TY sir

Comment: I'm sure you will remember it on the next time. ;)

Answer (score 1):

If you can't use sets, you could do this, it would work for both your lists.

```
int_list = [0,1,0,1,2,2,3,4,5,7,9,8,10,1,1,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]

ints = []
for i in int_list:
    if i not in ints:
        ints.append(i)
ints.sort()

>>> print ints
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

And for your list of characters:

```
char_list = ['z','r','a','z','x','b','z','a','f','f','f','x','t','t','o','p','a','b','v','e','q','p','c','x']

chars = []
for i in char_list:
    if i not in chars:
        chars.append(i)
chars.sort()

>>> print chars
['a', 'c', 'b', 'e', 'f', 'o', 'q', 'p', 'r', 't', 'v', 'x', 'z']
```

Answer (score 0):

This is old question but I am leaving this answer here

```
from collections import Counter
def dup_remover(lst):
    return list(Counter(lst))

>>> dup_remover(list2)
['a', 'c', 'b', 'e', 'f', 'o', 'q', 'p', 'r', 't', 'v', 'x', 'z']
```

Comment: Why `ele[0]`? For the general "keep only first copy" case, the answer is even simpler than you're making it: `def dup_remover(lst): return list(Counter(lst))`. Manually building up the `list` with `append`s is silly; you're already iterating a perfectly good `list`, so just return it. In any event, the questioner says they can't use `set`, so I doubt they could use `Counter` either.

Comment: @ShadowRanger what you said is true, I was in an illusion that I was using tuples which it really isn't. Updated now. Problem is solved but I just left this here to show that it can be done through Counter too for future reference.